# ifelse with two conditions numeric and categorical in R

Tags: r, if-statement, dplyr

I have the following dataset of which a subset is:

```
structure(list(First.Name = c(5006L, 5006L, 5006L, 5006L, 5006L, 
5006L, 5006L, 5006L, 5006L, 5006L, 5006L, 5006L), TimePoint = c(NA, 
NA, NA, NA, NA, "PRE", NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA), Year_Day = c(125, 
126, 127, 128, 129, 130, 131, 132, 133, 134, 135, 136), Week_Year = c(18, 
18, 19, 19, 19, 19, 19, 19, 19, 20, 20, 20), Session = c("Pre", 
"Pre", "Pre", "Pre", "Pre", "Pre", "Pre", "Pre", "Pre", "Post", 
"Post", "Post")), row.names = c(NA, -12L), class = c("tbl_df", 
"tbl", "data.frame"))
```

which looks like (with asterisks to denote the error):

```
# A tibble: 12 x 5
   First.Name TimePoint Year_Day Week_Year Session
        <int> <chr>        <dbl>     <dbl> <chr>  
 1       5006 NA             125        18 Pre    
 2       5006 NA             126        18 Pre    
 3       5006 NA             127        19 Pre    
 4       5006 NA             128        19 Pre    
 5       5006 NA             129        19 Pre    
 6       5006 PRE            130        19 Pre    
 7       5006 NA             131        19 **Pre**    
 8       5006 NA             132        19 **Pre**    
 9       5006 NA             133        19 **Pre**    
10       5006 NA             134        20 Post   
11       5006 NA             135        20 Post   
12       5006 NA             136        20 Post
```

I am trying to create a new column per subject called `Session` that contains the word "Pre" if the `Week_Year` is the beginning of the subject data *up until (and including)* `TimePoint` column contains the word "PRE" and all other rows should be "Post"

My ideal output from the subset above should be:

```
# A tibble: 12 x 5
   First.Name TimePoint Year_Day Week_Year Session
        <int> <chr>        <dbl>     <dbl> <chr>  
 1       5006 NA             125        18 Pre    
 2       5006 NA             126        18 Pre    
 3       5006 NA             127        19 Pre    
 4       5006 NA             128        19 Pre    
 5       5006 NA             129        19 Pre    
 6       5006 PRE            130        19 Pre    
 7       5006 NA             131        19 **Post**   
 8       5006 NA             132        19 **Post**   
 9       5006 NA             133        19 **Post**   
10       5006 NA             134        20 Post   
11       5006 NA             135        20 Post   
12       5006 NA             136        20 Post
```

I am trying variations of

```
df %>%
  group_by(First.Name) %>%
  mutate(Session = ifelse(TimePoint == "PRE" & Week_Year <= first(Week_Year) + 1, "Pre", "Post")) %>%
  ungroup()
```

but it is not outputting correctly. Help appreciated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can accomplish this by using `case_when` from the `dplyr` package with `lag` and `fill`.

```r
df <- structure(list(First.Name = c(5006L, 5006L, 5006L, 5006L, 5006L, 
5006L, 5006L, 5006L, 5006L, 5006L, 5006L, 5006L), TimePoint = c(NA, 
NA, NA, NA, NA, "PRE", NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA), Year_Day = c(125, 
126, 127, 128, 129, 130, 131, 132, 133, 134, 135, 136), Week_Year = c(18, 
18, 19, 19, 19, 19, 19, 19, 19, 20, 20, 20), Session = c("Pre", 
"Pre", "Pre", "Pre", "Pre", "Pre", "Pre", "Pre", "Pre", "Post", 
"Post", "Post")), row.names = c(NA, -12L), class = c("tbl_df", 
"tbl", "data.frame"))

library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)

df %>% 
  mutate(
    Session = case_when(
      TimePoint == "PRE" ~ "Pre",
      lag(TimePoint) == "PRE" ~ "Post")
    ) %>% 
    fill(Session, .direction = "updown") %>% 
  ungroup()

#> # A tibble: 12 x 5
#>    First.Name TimePoint Year_Day Week_Year Session
#>         <int> <chr>        <dbl>     <dbl> <chr>  
#>  1       5006 <NA>           125        18 Pre    
#>  2       5006 <NA>           126        18 Pre    
#>  3       5006 <NA>           127        19 Pre    
#>  4       5006 <NA>           128        19 Pre    
#>  5       5006 <NA>           129        19 Pre    
#>  6       5006 PRE            130        19 Pre    
#>  7       5006 <NA>           131        19 Post   
#>  8       5006 <NA>           132        19 Post   
#>  9       5006 <NA>           133        19 Post   
#> 10       5006 <NA>           134        20 Post   
#> 11       5006 <NA>           135        20 Post   
#> 12       5006 <NA>           136        20 Post
```

<sup>Created on 2021-02-01 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v0.3.0)</sup>

Answer (score 1):

```
df %>%
  mutate(Session = ifelse(row_number() > which(df$TimePoint == "PRE"), "Post", "Pre"))
```

Basically, the `which()` function finds the row number that has "PRE" in the `TimePoint` column.

The `mutate()` and `ifelse()` functions make it so every row that is larger than that row number will have "Post" for the `Session` column; otherwise, it will be "Pre".

Comment: I get the following error:

```
Problem with `mutate()` input `Session`.
i longer object length is not a multiple of shorter object length
i Input `Session` is `ifelse(...)`.
i The error occurred in group 1: First.Name = 5006.longer object length is not a multiple of shorter object lengthError: Problem with `mutate()` input `Session`.
x Input `Session` can't be recycled to size 40.
i Input `Session` is `ifelse(...)`.
i Input `Session` must be size 40 or 1, not 140.
i The error occurred in group 1: First.Name = 5006.
```

Comment: Do you have multiple rows that have "PRE" in the `TimePoint` column?

Answer (score 1):

From you data it seems that `TimePoint` defines the cutoff. So what I would do, is the following:

1. Define the Cutoff value

```
# Extract Cutoff Value
cutoff <- df %>% 
    select(
        TimePoint, Year_Day
    ) %>% 
    filter(
        TimePoint == "PRE"
    ) %>% select(Year_Day) %>% pull()
```

2. Then `mutate` your `session` variable

```
df %>% mutate(
    Session = if_else(
              Year_Day <= cutoff,"Pre","Post")
)
```

Which yields the following output;

```
# A tibble: 12 x 5
   First.Name TimePoint Year_Day Week_Year Session
        <int> <chr>        <dbl>     <dbl> <chr>  
 1       5006 NA             125        18 Pre    
 2       5006 NA             126        18 Pre    
 3       5006 NA             127        19 Pre    
 4       5006 NA             128        19 Pre    
 5       5006 NA             129        19 Pre    
 6       5006 PRE            130        19 Pre    
 7       5006 NA             131        19 Post   
 8       5006 NA             132        19 Post   
 9       5006 NA             133        19 Post   
10       5006 NA             134        20 Post   
11       5006 NA             135        20 Post   
12       5006 NA             136        20 Post
```

Answer (score 1):

Something like this? Sometimes it helps to construct an intermediate variable I've found

```
library(tidyverse)
df %>%
   group_by(First.Name) %>%mutate(r=  Year_Day>na.omit(Year_Day[TimePoint=='PRE']))%>%
   mutate(Session = ifelse(!r, "Pre", "Post")) %>%
   select(-r)%>%
   ungroup()
```

gives

```
First.Name TimePoint Year_Day Week_Year Session
        <int> <chr>        <dbl>     <dbl> <chr>  
 1       5006 NA             125        18 Pre    
 2       5006 NA             126        18 Pre    
 3       5006 NA             127        19 Pre    
 4       5006 NA             128        19 Pre    
 5       5006 NA             129        19 Pre    
 6       5006 PRE            130        19 Pre    
 7       5006 NA             131        19 Post   
 8       5006 NA             132        19 Post   
 9       5006 NA             133        19 Post   
10       5006 NA             134        20 Post   
11       5006 NA             135        20 Post   
12       5006 NA             136        20 Post
```

Answer (score 0):

You can find out the row index of `'PRE'` value in `TimePoint` and every row value before that is assigned `'Pre'`.

```
library(dplyr)

df %>%
  group_by(First.Name) %>%
  mutate(Session = ifelse(row_number() <= match('PRE', TimePoint) & 
                           Week_Year <= first(Week_Year) + 1, "Pre", "Post")) %>%
  ungroup()


#   First.Name TimePoint Year_Day Week_Year Session
#        <int> <chr>        <dbl>     <dbl> <chr>  
# 1       5006 NA             125        18 Pre    
# 2       5006 NA             126        18 Pre    
# 3       5006 NA             127        19 Pre    
# 4       5006 NA             128        19 Pre    
# 5       5006 NA             129        19 Pre    
# 6       5006 PRE            130        19 Pre    
# 7       5006 NA             131        19 Post   
# 8       5006 NA             132        19 Post   
# 9       5006 NA             133        19 Post   
#10       5006 NA             134        20 Post   
#11       5006 NA             135        20 Post   
#12       5006 NA             136        20 Post
```